# "npm install" install no dependencies library

Tags: npm

`redux-router@1.0.0-beta4` only has `deep-equal` as the dependencies.

redux-router/package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.6.14",
    "babel-core": "5.6.15",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "chai": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^1.3.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "0.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.3.1",
    "history": "^1.9.0",
    "jsdom": "^5.6.0",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^1.0.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.2",
    "react": "^0.14.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "1.0.0",
    "redux": "3.x",
    "redux-devtools": "^2.1.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "sinon": "^1.15.4",
    "webpack": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

But `history` is installed in `node_modules` when I install `redux-router@1.0.0-beta4`.

Why is `history` installed in it?
`history` is used in `redux-router@1.0.0-beta4`. But it doesn't specify its dependencies same as `react`, `redux`...

It occurs regardless of npm versions.

npm v3.4.1

```
%  npm i redux-router@1.0.0-beta4
/Users/koba04/test
└─┬ redux-router@1.0.0-beta4
  └── deep-equal@1.0.1
%  ls node_modules/
deep-equal   redux-router
% ls node_modules/redux-router/node_modules
history
```

npm v2.14.3

```
%  npm i redux-router@1.0.0-beta4
redux-router@1.0.0-beta4 node_modules/redux-router
└── deep-equal@1.0.1
% ls node_modules
redux-router
% ls node_modules/redux-router/node_modules
deep-equal history
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an npm's bug and fixed it.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/133